# TTS bot messages overlap

Tags: javascript, bots, text-to-speech, message, twitch

I created a tts bot for twitch that works great, but every time any messages come to close together it tries to say them at the same time and it becomes nothing but noise. Does anybody know how to fix this?

```
var tmi = require('tmi.js');
var say = require('say');

//BOT CONNECTION OPTIONS
var options = {
    options: {
        debug: false
    },
    connection: {
        cluster: "as",
        reconnect: true
    },
    identity: {
        username: "",
        password: ""
    },
    channels: [""]
};

var client = new tmi.client(options);
client.connect(); 

client.on("chat", function (channel, userstate, message, self) {
    say.speak(userstate.username + " says " + message);
});
```

Comment: Insert script here (no image, but code) please.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the say library supports any kind of "I'm finished" notification, so your best bet is just implementing a queue that has a set delay of n seconds, where n is roughly the maximum amount of time you'd expect reading a message to take.

Comment: Could you give me an example for making this queue @JBC

Comment: You could do something as simple as a `setInterval()`.  Each time your on event triggers you add something to a collection, each time `setInterval` runs you take an item off the collection and play it (if any).  There are also libraries like `asyncjs` that have more robust queues built in (called `asyncQueue` in that library).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
skipping

```
 client.on("chat", function (channel, userstate, message, self) {
    if(!say.isSpeaking()){
       say.speak(userstate.username + " says " + message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    }
 });
```

OR ADD txt in que

```
 client.on("chat", function (channel, userstate, message, self) {
    say.speak(userstate.username + " says " + message, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);
 });
```